# Can anybody validate this WolframAlpha computation?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Can anybody validate this WolframAlpha computation?

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GCD%5BDivisorSigma%5B1%2Cx%5D%2C+DivisorSigma%5B1%2Cx%5E2%5D%5D

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PolynomalGCD` is a simple operation: it takes the GCD of polynomials. It doesn't know about transcendental functions or number-theoretic operations or anything: anything it sees that isn't a number is considered a formal variable.

So, it is treating `DivisorSigma[1,x]` as one indeterminate variable, and `DivisorSigma[1,x^2]` as another indeterminate variable. As these are different indeterminate variables, their polynomial gcd is 1, no different from asking for the gcd of `x` and `y`.

If there are any algebraic relationships between $\sigma_1(x)$ and $\sigma_1(x^2)$, you have to work them out and do an appropriate substitution *before* plugging into the gcd function.

`GCD` is even simpler: it acts on integers. If you don't give it integers, it can't do anything. WolframAlpha tried to be helpful here, and it recognized that you didn't give it integers, so it assumed you meant to take the gcd as polynomials.

Mathematica (and by extension WolframAlpha) can't even (directly) tell you, for example, that $\gcd(x(x+1), 2) > 1$ for every integer value you plug in for $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation @Hurkyl.